# Give a general formula for the determinant of $A_n$

Tags: linear-algebra

> $A_n$ is the $n \times n$ matrix over $\mathbb{R}$ such that the entry in the $i$th row and $j$th column equals $1$ if $|i-j| \leq 1$ and $0$ otherwise. Give (/prove) a general formula in terms of $n$ for the determinant $A_n$.

How would one go about doing this? I mostly have experience with $2 \times 2$ and $3 \times 3$ determinants, so I have no clue how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix $A_n$ is a [tridiagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix):
$$ A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots& 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots &\ddots  & \ddots & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}. $$

The determinant of such matrices can be found by solving a recurrence relation. Denote the determinant of $A_n$ by $d_n$. By expanding along the first row, we have

$$ d_n = d_{n-1} - 1 \cdot (1 \cdot d_{n-2}) = d_{n-1} - d_{n-2} $$

with initial values $d_0 = 1$ and $d_1 = 1$. Writing the first few values of the sequence, we have

$$ 1, \,\, 1, 0, -1, \,\, -1, 0, 1, \,\, 1, 0, -1, \,\, -1, 0, 1, \ldots $$

so you can see the pattern. You can write an explicit formula for $d_n$ and prove it rigorously using induction.